# Did Verne's "Two Years' Vacation" influence Golding's "Lord of the Flies"?

Tags: intertextuality, lord-of-the-flies, william-golding, jules-verne, two-years-vacation

Jules Verne's 1888 novel [*Two Years' Vacation* (*Deux ans de vacances*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Years%27_Vacation) is about a group of schoolboys who find themselves having to survive on a deserted island. The theme seems similar to the more famous *Lord of the Flies* written by William Golding sixty-five years later. Wikipedia remarks on the common elements between the two stories, but not about whether such elements are due to direct influence or simply a common genre.

**Is there any evidence that *Lord of the Flies* was influenced by *Two Years' Vacation*?** Any plot elements that are *too* similar to be coincidence, or Easter-egg homages in the story? Or extratextual evidence such as remarks by Golding, or even any evidence that he read *Two Years' Vacation* before writing his own story?

Comment: I wavered between [tag:intertextuality] and [tag:french-literature] for the 5th tag here. Woe for the 5-tag limit.

Comment: https://www.william-golding.co.uk/lord-flies-coral-island shows direct links to R.M. Ballantyne's Coral Island